# form-manager plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html

I have used form-manager plugin for form page. I have successfully implement it. But i want to change field type. That is I want to change text field to select field. But I could not chnage it. Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of your plugin? Doesn't the plugin come with options where you can design the form. If it does then all you have to do is to edit the form and replace the text field with a select field. Hope this helps.